# Oracle result cache behaviour

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, oracle11g

Oracle by default caching the query results and function results.

I have noticed this with AutoTrace utility, Where the physical reads are huge on first execution, but from next execution onwards it reduced dramatically.

Than what is the importance of **query result cache**, **function result Cache**?

Could some one help on this to understand better.

Comment: Physical read reduction are related to the buffer cache; are you confusing terms?

Comment: @AlexPoole I really do not have much idea how on this, Could you brief something?

Comment: You might be better off starting with the documentation; [buffer cache](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29505_01/server.1111/e16638/memory.htm#i29118), and the [query and function result caches](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41573/memory.htm#PFGRF986). Those are from the performance tuning guide, which should help explain their significance.

Comment: @AlexPoole, How the buffer cache gets invalidated, I have tried restarting server, Updating Physical table. But still i noticed Physical reads are 0.

Comment: The buffer cache - indeed all of these - are memory structures, so they're all reset if the DB restarts. The first time any query runs after a restart it will read from disk and start to populate the buffer cache in the process. You can also force it to reset with a flush but that's very rarely necessary or advisable.

Comment: Oracle does not "by default" cache the query results or function results. It automatically caches the blocks read from disk, which is why your performance is improved. This is normally sufficient, but in some cases you might want a whole query or function call to be cached as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple: when you have query result cache the query will most likely not executed once again - the result will be provided from that cache. In case of absence of that functionality Oracle will do query on cached data (buffer cache) that is more expensive. Query result cache might be implemented on client side as well that may eliminate even round trip to server.